# One-loop diagram self-energy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, self-energy

I need to find the diagram contributing to the self energy of $\varphi$. Say I had an interaction term in the Lagrangian 2 $\varphi$ real scalar fields, and one $\psi$ real scalar field, $\varphi^2\psi$, my questions are, each of the fields contributes a propagator that enters each vertex? And the loop is made up of only $\varphi$ propagators? or one $\varphi$ and one $\psi$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, each of these terms contributes one propagator entering the vertex. In this case the loop, for the self-energy of $\varphi$, will constitute of one $\varphi$ propagator and one $\psi$ propagator. The reason is as follows: we want to calculate the self-energy for $\varphi$, which means for a process where $\varphi$ enters and $\varphi$ exists the process. So the diagram will consist of one line (propagator) $\varphi$ entering and one leaving. Now we put a vertex, which can connect to two liens of $\varphi$, and one of $\psi$. One option is to connect the one entering and one leaving and then close $\psi$ onto itself, but this usually doesn't contribute anything as $\langle \psi \rangle = 0$ (if this is not the case in your theory, then this term will contribute to the self-energy). The next option is to add another vertex, and then connect one $\varphi$ line between them and one $\psi$ line between them, creating the loop.

Comment: thank you so much that clarifies  alot